# filtrado typescript

Tags: php, ionic, typescript

Necesito hacer que la consulta de función "clientes" sea ingresada en la función "getimtems" para poder filtrar los datos
Aqui obtengo la consulta:

```
clientes() {
    this.userData.accion="consultaclientes";
     this.restprovider.Registro(this.userData).then((result) => {
        this.data = result;
        console.log(this.data);
      }, (err) => {
        this.presentToast(err);
      });
  }
```

El resultado de la consulta necesito ingresarla en esta función:

```
getItems(ev) {

    this.clientes();

  var val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.result = this.result.filter((result) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }

  }
```

esta es la consulta que hago en php:

```
case 'consultaclientes':
  $nombre = $request->nombre;


    $sql2=("SELECT * FROM `cliente` WHERE nombre = '$nombre'" );
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql2);
    //$row1= $resultado->fetch_array();

    $json_array= array();
    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
       $json_array[]=$fila;
    };

    echo json_encode($json_array);
                exit(0);

 break;
```

Comment: Hola @Ronald López,
Si no entiendo mal, lo que necesitas es devolver la Promise que te devuelve `this.restprovider.Registro(this.userData)...` para usarla en la función `getItems(ev)`, ¿verdad?

Answer (score 0):

segun entiendo necesitas filtrar tu resultado de la consulta

puedes emplear lo siguiente

```
public function llamadoDatos(){

return this.userData.accion="consultaclientes";
     this.restprovider.Registro(this.userData).then((result) => {
        this.data = result;
        console.log(this.data);
        return this.data;
      }, (err) => {
        this.presentToast(err);
      });
}
```

y en la funcion de filtrado poner algo similar a lo siguiente

```
public async getItems(ev): items[] {

 try {
  let datos = await this.llamadoDatos();
} catch(error: any) {
 console.error(error);
}
  var val = datos.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.result = this.result.filter((result) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    } else {
  return val
}

  }
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda
Salud.